PITR Backup solution for PostgreSQL running under Windows
I am new to PostgreSQL and come from a SQL Server world. I am trying to create a transactional log backup process for PostgreSQL to run under Windows. I believe the terminology is PITR and Archiving but I am trying to find the best tool for this and instructions under windows commandline/SQL code
I have looked at pgBackRest but cannot see how to install and configure under windows.
I am running PostgreSQL 16

Product recommendations are off topic here. Having said that, if you are stuck with Windows, you should look at commercial tools like Netbackup or Veeam, or develop something on your own, because there's precious little support for Windows-based solutions from the OSS community.
